# debugging flex maven application with intellij idea

Tags: apache-flex, maven, intellij-idea

I have flex application consisting of several modules which is configured using maven. I'm using flexmojos plugin to build the application. When I try to build the application using maven it builds successfully. But I need debugging features of Intellij Idea (i'm using 10.0 version). So at first step I run maven compile command to generate *-configs.xml to enable Intellij idea compile my application. At second step i run IDE's compile(or make) command and it says:

```
unable to open '{path_to_repository}\.m2\repository\com\adobe\flex\framework\playerglobal\4.5.1.21328\10.2\playerglobal.swc'
```

I'm sure this file is in this maven repository directory. How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have spaces in {path_to_repository}? The problem with spaces comes from Adobe's compiling tool. It is workarounded at IntelliJ IDEA side since version 11.

Also IDEA supports remote debugging, you can select corresponding option in Flex Run configuration (uncheck Make before launch as you'll need to compile and run the app manually). Although in IDEA 10 the option is called "Debug already running Flash Player" you can first launch the run configuration and then launch SWF manually, it will connect to the debugger automatically. Wording is fixed in IDEA 11.

By the way the best place to ask questions about IntelliJ IDEA is our forum: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/ideacommunity

Comment: Yes, I have spaces in {path_to_repository}. I guess this is the cause. Thank you.

Comment: The problem with spaces comes from Adobe's compiling tool. It is workarounded at IntelliJ IDEA side since version 11.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually debug right out of the target folder (at least with eclipse), so you can build the project "normally" using maven then point the debug configuration to start up the html/swf from the target folder (debug property in flexmojos configuration must be true, but I believe this is the default).  Sorry I don't know IntelliJ so I can't comment on that.